# Fixed effects model with cluster data

Tags: r

I built a fixed effects model using the lm function. I had previously created price clusters of independent variables (cluster number * price) with an end goal of estimating demand elasticities.  Am I correct that the factor function ( + factor(Tulsa$Cluster)-1) at the end provides different intercepts (b0's) for each of the pricing cluster independent variables?

```
model.fixed = lm(Tulsa$ln_volume  ~ Tulsa$Price_Cluster_1
+ Tulsa$Price_Cluster_2
+ Tulsa$Price_Cluster_3
+ Tulsa$Price_Cluster_4
+ Tulsa$Price_Cluster_5
+ Tulsa$PC1
+ Tulsa$PC2
+ Tulsa$PC3
+ Tulsa$PC4
+ factor(Tulsa$Cluster)-1,data=Tulsa)
```

[image: Regression Results]

The coefficients for the price clusters are the right direction and make intuitive sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us a sample of your actual data frame and provide more context about what you're trying to do. If you're trying to create a random effects model for clustered data, the `lm` function won't do that, but you can create such a model with the `lme4` or `nlme` packages. It also looks like you might be manually creating dummy variables for each category level within a given data column. This is unnecessary. Most R regression functions (like `lm`) take care of this automatically.

Comment: Also, in your regression formula, remove all of the `Tulsa$`. It's unnecessary, since the data frame object is passed into `lm` (or other model functions) with the `data` argument, and also undesirable, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623935/lm-and-predict-agreement-of-data-frame-names).

Comment: Thanks - added the regression results. I THINK the correct interpretation is that the factors at the bottom are individual cluster intercepts with the cross product betas being the elasticity coefficients.